# python subprocess communicate with mplayer via bash

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess, mplayer

I am running this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

cmd = "mplayer -slave -input file=/home/user/mplayer-control duha.mp4 -loop 3000"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

then in terminal I want to pause mplayer with `echo "pause" > /home/user/mplayer-control`
But mplayer is not responding to my commands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you run the same command in the shell? (something like: `cmd </dev/null >output`)

Comment: this video explains completely about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKqkYGom0Y0